# Play Services Resolver not able to fetch Firebase dependencies (Unity/Firebase)

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

I tried to implement Firebase Auth in my app but I the Play Services Resolver can't fetch the dependencies. I did everything the way the Firebase docs said.

```
Resolution failed

Failed to fetch the following dependencies:
com.google.firebase:firebase-app-unity:4.2.0@aar
com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-unity:4.2.0@aar


UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:LogDelegate(String, LogLevel)
Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport:Log(String, LogLevel, Boolean)
GooglePlayServices.ResolverVer1_1:LogMissingDependenciesError(List`1)
GooglePlayServices.<DoResolutionUnsafe>c__AnonStorey18:<>m__28(List`1)
GooglePlayServices.<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey14:<>m__20(Result)
GooglePlayServices.<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey15:<>m__2B()
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:PumpUpdateQueue()
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()
```

Comment: What are versions of Unity, Android SDK and Play Services?

Comment: Unity 5.6.3p2 AndroidSDK not sure but I updated it like a week ago. Play Services is from the newest Unity Firebase SDK